# Image is not displaying in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have img tag in my view file (yii frame work). and image is displayed in most of the times. some times the images are not displaying. when I inspect the element, then it shows the img  path as  src="hhhh://localhost/projects/aaa/images/sample-img-left.png". here for http://, hhhh:// comes. Iam not getting any idea with how this hhhh comes. help me please

Comment: maybe the code where you generate the link would help?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl` to get the location where your project resides, then append it with the image path. 
For Eg. 
`<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/images/sample-img-left.png"  ?>" />`